# How to read the data from mysql database and insert it into an implemented Hashtable?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I need to modify my program to read the username and passwords from mysql database and insert it into a hashtable but I cannot get it to insert into the hashtable. What am I doing wrong?

```
private static final Map<String, String> accounts = new Hashtable<>();
     public static void main(String args[]){  
        try {  
         Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( 
                 "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","");  
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from account"); 
         accounts.put(rs.getString("username"), 
                         rs.getString("password"));
        while(rs.next())  
        System.out.println(rs.getString("username") + " " + 
                rs.getString("password"));  
        con.close();  
        }
            catch(Exception e){ 
                System.out.println(e);
            }  

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html).

This line will not work:

```
accounts.put(rs.getString("username"), 
             rs.getString("password"));
```

Because you haven't asserted that the `ResultSet` has any data in it.

I.e. you have to call rs.next() at least (to ensure there is data in there) before you can extract data from the *current* row.